# VS Load Test Scenario - How can we add custom scenario info to database

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I have a Load Test project that works perfectly and is able to saves all the perf counter in the LoadTest db as expected.

I wanted to add some specific scenario attributes information to my test run.

Therefore when I create a report in Excel at the end, ill be able to filter based on those attributes

**Example:**

Environment Attribute: (QA, PreProd, Production)

Target Attribute: (UI, API,..)

I searched everywhere but couldn't find the information. Not sure if I have to create a new table in that DB and populate it myself, or if there is another easier way.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I have achieved to doing what you ask is by modifying the "reporting names" of requests to include the wanted information. On one test I added a test case that executed a small number of times (so few that the overall results would not be skewed). It had two requests. The first collected some data and saved it to a context parameter. The second had a `PreRequest` plugin that wrote the data to the `ReportingName` field of that request. (Experiments showed that setting the field in a `PostRequest` plugin had no effect.)

Another approach I have used is have a `PostWebTest` plugin that writes a line of useful data to a logging file, so I get one line per test case executed.

It may be possible to add another table to the load test database, but I would wonder whether it would be properly handled by the `Open`, `Import`, `Export` and `Delete` commands of the **Open and Manage Test Results** window.